# alarmmanager and service

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've this code to autostart my service, I think that AlarmON.class runs when alarmmanager wait 60seconds but no it is. Where's the error?

When I reboot I see both toast: "service created" and "service started".

thanks for the help!

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.startatboot.UnUsedService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

and a service:

```
public class UnUsedService extends Service {
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null; 
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(UnUsedService.this, AlarmON.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(UnUsedService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),    pendingIntent);

Toast.makeText(UnUsedService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}};
```

Comment: I think you have to call super.onStart()

Comment: super.onStart(); after public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) { cause an error in eclipse. Also add: super.onStart(intent, startId); nothing happen :-(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Because...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); does the same thing.
```

That's like saying give me the current time and then set the current time to the current time.

Also try moving the code from onStart to onCreate, I've seen issues where Android won't call onStart for services.

Based on your comment I edited my post.

Do you have your AlarmON service registered in your manifest?  For example in the application section:

```
<service
    android:name=".AlarmON"
    android:label="@string/service_name" >
</service>
```

Comment: understood. The problem is: after 60 seconds, class AlarmON does not starts... it's only for purpose test. Next will write a code to have 2 alarm times every days. Using log nothing happen. Thanks.